# How to pass an object as function's parameter without getting Unexpected identifier error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I tried to passed the object as parameter in function getReqDetail but it returned Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. But when i passed a simple value(integer,boolean,string) as parameter such as data[i].id, it worked. So how do i passed the object as parameter

the data/object is from ajax function jquery

```
function agetAllRequests(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: `http://localhost:8080/api/requests`,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("yes. data: " + data);
            if (data) {
                if (len > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        if(data[i]) {                            
                            console.log(data[i]);  
                            txt += `
                                    <tr class="hov" onclick="getReqDetails(${data[i]})">
                                           <td>${data[i].id}</td> 
                                           <td>${data[i].status}</td> 
                                           <td>${data[i].user.email}</td> 
                                           <td>${data[i].message}</td> 
                                           <td>${new Date(data[i].createdAt).toLocaleString()}</td>
                                    </tr>`;
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt){
                        $("#requestList").html(txt);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('errorCode: ' + error.status + ' . Message: ' + error.responseText);
        }
    });
}
function getReqDetails(data){
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```

**EDIT :**
note: function getReqDetails is outside of ajax function

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKAB0.png)

Comment: Attach the listener properly with `addEventListener` instead of using an inline attribute (which is as bad as `eval`)

Comment: Please spend some time to properly indent your code. The braces are floating everywhere except where they should be in nicely formatted code. You have two more opening than closing braces, which makes your function *part* of the `success` callback function, despite what you are telling us in the "EDIT" ;-)

Comment: After your recent edit, you still have one more opening brace than closing, and your indentation is not right at all. Please use proper indentation. It is the first thing a programmer would need to get right as it will solve many issues even before they surface. Hint: already on the second line of your code the indentation goes wrong, and again on the 5th, 8th, ...etc.

Comment: @trincot sure, sorry, still green here

Comment: I see you are really struggling to get the indentation right. Make sure that after every opening brace, the next line is indented more, and that each closing brace is indented less than the code above it. The body of the `for` loop is still not OK as regards indentation.

Comment: More importantly, you should add the whole `ajax` call, because the `success` property is part of an object literal, and the function `getReqDetails` is now dangling inside the object, which is a syntax error. Please make sure to provide code you have tested.

Comment: Is `getReqDetails` a global function, or is this code placed within some other bigger function? NB/ you managed again to not indent your code properly. Do you not value the comments I made on the importance of indentation?

Comment: @trincot yes it is a global function, sorry for the bad indentation sir, still trying to get rid of those bad habits

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `` `onclick="getReqDetails(${data[i]})` `` will resolve to a string. Because `data[i]` is not a string it is converted to one, ie. "[object Object]". This makes the `onclick` attribute look like this:

```
onclick="getReqDetails([object Object])"
```

But that code is not valid JavaScript, hence the error.

In order to pass the *object* to the function, you should really not use the `onclick` attribute, which must have a string value. Instead bind a click handler, as follows:

```
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("yes. data: " + data);
        if (!data || !data.length) return;
        $("#requestList").empty(); // Clear whatever content there was before
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var item = data[i]; // Use a local variable to avoid repetition
            if(!item) continue;                            
            console.log(item);
            // Use jQuery methods to add the content and bind a click handler
            $("#requestList").append(
                $("<tr>").addClass("hov").append(
                    $("<td>").text(item.id),
                    $("<td>").text(item.status),
                    $("<td>").text(item.user.email),
                    $("<td>").text(item.message.id),
                    $("<td>").text(new Date(item.createdAt).toLocaleString())
                ).click(getReqDetails.bind(null, item)); // <-- click handler for TR
            );
        }
    },
```

Comment: sir, is there another way than `getReqDetails.bind(null, item)`?
@trincot

Comment: just curious because i m still new to JavaScript, sir @trincot

Comment: Yes, like `.click((function (item) { return function() { getReqDetails(item)}; })(item))`, or you could define `item` in block scope and use an arrow function: `let item = ...; .... .click(_ => getReqDetails(item))`, ...etc, but `bind` is really the simplest for your current code.

Answer (score 2):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) allows population of variables ( `${myVar}` ) at runtime but the result will be always a string so the evaluation of your template will result in `getReqDetails([object Object])`.

What you can do is render a serializable value from your object or store a reference to the index then process it in the called function `getReqDetails()`.

Try to pass a simple value to your string function:

```js
var data = [{id: 1},{id: 2}, {id: 3},];
if (data) {
    var len = data.length;
    var txt = ``;
       if (len > 0) {
         for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(data[i]) {                           
            txt += `
            <tr class="hov" onclick="getReqDetails(${data[i].id})">
                  <td>...<td>
            </tr>`;}
}
if(txt){
           $("#requestList").html(txt);
}
}
function getReqDetails(reqId){
     console.log(reqId)
     return reqId;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="requestList" />
```

Comment: thanks, when i passed a simple value it worked, but when i tried to pass the object as param, it returned the same error "unexpected unique identifier"

Comment: this is due to the fact your are converting your object to a string, if you do not define a single value, when concatenating string through "+" you are forcing to a string conversion, obtaining "getReqDetails([object Object])". You could use JSX instead of string if you want to retain refereces to methods and objects efficiently

Answer (score 1):

I think it's problematic in the first place that the `getReqDetails` function is inside the `success` item in the AJAX statement. Since it's an `onclick` function,  I think it should be globally defined.

Answering your main question, the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` is usually called when you have issues with your code syntactically. You may have extra/missing brackets, double parentheses, et cetera.

Looking at the second `if` statement in your code, you have some issues with your brackets. It should look like this:

```
  if (len > 0)
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(data[i]) {                           
            console.log(data[i]);
            txt += `
            <!--<tr class="hov" onclick="getReqDetails(${data[i].id})">-->
            <tr class="hov" onclick="getReqDetails(${data[i]})">
                <td>...<td>
            </tr>`;
         }
     }
```

Here are the changes I made:

- I remove the `{` in your `if (len > 0) {` since you have only one
  statement inside it, which is the `for` statement.
- I add another closing bracket (`}`) for the `for` statement.

I hope this will fix your problem. I suggest you use a powerful code editor like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/) for syntax highlighting, error checking, debugging, and so much more. If you prefer working on a terminal, I suggest using [Vim](https://www.vim.org/).

Additionally, I strongly suggest you define the `getReqDetails` function outside the AJAX statement. I think, the reason your code works using an integer as an input, is because numbers on Javascript (if I'm not mistaken) doesn't have a `length` property -- Which leads your script not calling any error, because the value of `len` is `null`.

**EDIT**

Since you want the object to be a parameter on the onclick function, you need to convert it first to a string. You can do it by replacing `${data[i]}` to `${JSON.stringify(data[i])}`. Then on the `getReqDetails` function, you use the `JSON.parse()` function to read the param as an object.

Updated `txt` variable

txt += 
   `<tr class="hov" onclick="getReqDetails(${JSON.stringify(data[i])})">
        <td>...<td>
    </tr>`;

Updated `getReqDetails` function:

```
function getReqDetails(stringifiedObject){
    var data = JSON.parse(stringifiedObject)

    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must parse to JSON stringify and clean special char:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data[i]).replace(/\"/g,"'")
```

now it's working!