# How to fix Javascript onclick call?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm having trouble understanding why my onclick buttons are not working. My onclick buttons are within a JS function which modifies the HTML.

Here is the function which includes the onclick buttons:

```
const bookmarkHTML = (bookmark) => {
    let html = '';
    if (bookmark.url.includes('https://') || bookmark.url.includes('http://')) {
        const li = `
            <li>
                <div class="row card-margin">
                    <div class="col s12 m12 card-padding">
                        <div class="card-panel teal card-size">
                            <img src='${'https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=' + bookmark.url}' alt='icon' class='img-size'>
                            <a class='white-text' href='${bookmark.url}' target='_blank'>${bookmark.website}</a>
                            <button class='btn-flat waves-light btn-small right' onclick='switchCategory(bookmark)'><i class='material-icons left'>compare_arrows</i>switch</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        `;
        html += li;
    } else {
        const li = `
            <li>
                <div class="row card-margin">
                    <div class="col s12 m12 card-padding">
                        <div class="card-panel teal card-size">
                            <img src='${'https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=' + bookmark.url}' alt='icon' class='img-size'>
                            <a class='white-text' href='${'https://' + bookmark.url}' target='_blank'>${bookmark.website}</a>
                            <button class='btn-flat waves-light btn-small right' onclick='switchCategory(bookmark)'><i class='material-icons left'>compare_arrows</i>switch</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        `;
        html += li;
    }
    console.log('HTML:', html);
    return html;
}
```

Here is the function called in onclick:

```
switchCategory = (bookmark) => {
    if (bookmark.favorite) {
        bookmark.favorite = false;
    } else {
        bookmark.favorite = true;
    }
}
```

If needed, here is the function which calls the bookmarkHTML function:

```
const setupBookmarks = (data) => {
    let favoritesHTML = '';
    let bookmarksHTML = '';
    if (data.length) {
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const bookmark = doc.data();
            if (bookmark.favorite) {
                favoritesHTML += bookmarkHTML(bookmark);
            } else {
                bookmarksHTML += bookmarkHTML(bookmark);
            }
        })
    }
    favoriteList.innerHTML = favoritesHTML;
    bookmarkList.innerHTML = bookmarksHTML;
}
```

When I click on the button with onclick, I get this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: bookmark is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like the onclick handler is the string  'switchCategory(bookmark)'. Use the actual function with parameter?

Comment: @NVRM Could you explain further? What am I doing wrong with backticks?

Comment: @JhalaaChinoy I just tried that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @NVRM That isn't part of the problem. StackOverflow for some reason messed up the syntax highlighting. On VSCode, the highlighting shows up correctly, and when I run my code, everything shows up as it should. onclick still doesn't work, though.

Comment: @NVRM I did try it before my last comment. It didn't change anything. I'll keep it with the double quotes, but it didn't change any of the actions of the code. All the links worked before and still work now.

Comment: What frontend library are you using?

Comment: @RauboLuk All I am using in this project is Firebase and MaterializeCSS. Otherwise it is just vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is happening because when you are passing an object inside template literals `switchCategory(bookmark)` this object is converted to `[object Object]`. A workaround for this may be converting that object to string `switchCategory(${JSON.stringify(bookmark)})` but it won't do the job in your case because you are mutating that object later. I think that adding [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) may be the way to resolve this. [I also found similar problem so u can get more information about that and maybe a better solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942509/how-to-pass-an-object-as-functions-parameter-without-getting-unexpected-identif)